# A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 2 [character 3 line 1]

Tags: java, json, http

I have written the following code to get the `JSON` response from the `url` which has authentication. Further,this response is in the format of the `JSON` array. Response is kind of big so I have attached `JSON` response in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gSM1CXQlB7eJQXXsY8_G3koJWuyZB8S/view?usp=sharing

I want to fetch the `user id` and their `role` in the form of `JSON object`. However I'm facing this error.Can anybody help me what went wrong and could you suggest any modification in the code?

```java
package url_request;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONParing {

    private static HttpURLConnection connection;
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String usernameColonPassword = "uname:pass";
        String basicAuthPayload = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(usernameColonPassword.getBytes());

        BufferedReader reader;
        String line;

        StringBuffer responseContent = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://ucf6-zfon-fa-ext.oracledemos.com/hcmRestApi/scim/Users");

            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            int status = connection.getResponseCode();

            // for testing the connection
            // System.out.println(status);

            if (status > 299) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContent.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseContent.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            // System.out.println(responseContent.toString());
            parse(responseContent.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }
    public static String parse(String responseBody) {
        JSONArray albums;
        try {
            albums = new JSONArray(responseBody);

            for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i ++) {
                JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = album.getInt("id");
                int role = album.getInt("roles");
                System.out.println(id + " " + role);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the `uname` and `pass` fields, I will add the credential of the URL.

Comment: You need to get the 'Resource' node  first, the main body it not an Array. You are parsing the response body as an Array, so JsonParser is expecting [ to be the first character, but instead he gets {

Comment: Ok,can you edit/repost the code and suggest me accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for your example, althought I had to change some types, there were problems with casting

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> parse(String responseBody) {
    JSONObject resourcesNode = new JSONObject(responseBody); // incoming payload is an object, not an Array
    Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        JSONArray albums = resourcesNode.getJSONArray("Resources"); // get to the 
                          //Resource array, that holds desired data

        for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject album = albums.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = album.getString("id"); //id was type of String, not int
            if(album.has("roles")){ // not all entries had roles, safety check
                Set<String> userRoles =new HashSet<>();
                JSONArray roles = album.getJSONArray("roles");
                for(int j=0;j<roles.length();j++){
                    userRoles.add(roles.get(j).toString());
                }
                results.put(id, userRoles);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}
```